# Flattening of File Tree when using Grunt Copy Task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

Not sure if I'm missing something but I have the following grunt setup for grunt-contrib-copy tasks.

```
copy: {
  build: {
    files: {
      "server-dist/": "server/**/*.!(coffee)",
      "client-dist/": "client/**/*.!(coffee)"
    }
  }
}
```

The client-dist copies as I expect recursively running through the file tree but the server-dist all sub-folders get flattened to the base folder. Any ideas why this is happening? Here is the i/o

```
server/
  views/
    errors/
      404.jade
    layouts/
      base.jade
```

becomes

```
server/
  errors/
  layouts/
    base.jade
```

the views folder gets completely blown out. One more thing...when I removed !(coffee) it works but I need to exclude coffee files since I have a grunt-coffee watch task running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `grunt-contrib-copy` task has a sophisticated logic that's trying to automatically detect the base directory for copying source files (see [related issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/issues/12))

The solution is to explicitly specify the [`basePath`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/#basepath-string) option:

```
copy: {
  build: {
    files: {
      "server-dist/": "server/**/*!(.coffee)"
    },
    options: {
      basePath: 'server' // base directory in the source path
    }
  }
}
```

**P.S.** I'm not sure, however, why removing `!(.coffee)` changes the behaviour for you. I tried the same on my local machine and get the same results when specifying `"server/**/*"` instead of `"server/**/*.!(coffee)"` (i.e. the `views` folder is skipped)

Comment: awesome! that works but one more thing...in the example I have, there are two basePaths server + client. I'd rather not have two separate copy tasks buildServer + buildClient...I'll do it if I have to but is there another way. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a way you can do that with the current implementation of the task. You may want to talk to contributors in the issue I linked in my answer...

Comment: btw: `basePath` was changed to `cwd` in v0.4.0rc5, see: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy/#release-history

Answer (score 9):

A followup to zacks comment:

```
copy: {  
    mytask: {  
        files: [  
        {expand:true, cwd:'dev-js/abc/', dest:'js/test/', src:['def.js']}  
        ]  
    }  
}
```

This copies the file `./dev-js/abc/def.js` to `./js/test/def.js` - at least on my 0.4.1 version. Zacks comment and the link included was very helpful, especially the fact, that `basePath` has been replaced.

Comment: I didn't expect copying files to take a few hours to figure out, but oh well, this helped me out at least.

Comment: Worked for me! Finaly!!! Thank u very very very much!!! I search this for months!